# Read plist inside ~/Library/Preferences/

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm trying to access in ~/Library/Preferences/ but my code doesn't work.

```
NSString *resPath = @"~/Library/Preferences/";

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *filenames = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:resPath error:&error];

    if (!error)

    {

        for (NSString * filename in filenames)

        {

                NSLog(@"%@", filename);

        }
    }
```

Maybe I should ask for some permission.. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you need to find the Preferences folder?  To access your own preferences, use `NSUserDefaults`.  To access a different one, use `CFPreferences`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `NSString` method: `stringByExpandingTildeInPath` to expand the `~` into the full path.

```
NSString *resPath = [@"~/Library/Preferences/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSLog(@"resPath: %@", resPath);
```

Output:

> resPath: /Volumes/User/me/Library/Preferences

Comment: You are absolutly right! Sorry for the silly question.